# How does a C# Api read the appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, console-application, webapi

I wonder how the `startup.cs` knows of the `appsettings.json` file, I can't seem to find a setting in the `startup.cs` or `program.cs` of the api.

Standard program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Standard startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add `appsettings.json` to a console app but then I had to do the injection of the file manually. With this piece of code:

```
configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
                .Build();
```

Comment: The default host builder of asp.net does all behind the scenes.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c0662e8129beaf93b8050d39a863cc6d16a0308c/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L188-L223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application knows about these appsettings files thanks to the call to the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` method in program.cs .

As mentioned here in the [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#default-builder-settings), this method enables some default behavior, such as loading app configuration from:

> - appsettings.json.
> - appsettings.{Environment}.json.
> - User secrets when the app runs in the Development environment.
> - Environment variables.
> - Command-line arguments.